# can't run any project in Flutter. Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, sdk, build.gradle

i've tried to solve this issue for 4 days in a row, searched wholeover stack and other sites. when i try to run any project, it gives Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i've tried all the popular solutions like: `delete .lock file, flutter clean, flutter pub upgrade, flutter upgrade, and  flutter run --no-sound-null-safety.` nothing changes.

i can show output of flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
```

i'm not using visual studio, only Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its because of the SDK you are currently using.
You can try to download Flutter SDK again and locate an another location. Then change the sdk - environment variables with the new sdk location.